# Adding variables to namespace in Visual C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a namespace with a series of `static` functions. Snippet:

```
#ifndef CONGREGATION_DATABASE_MANAGER
#define CONGREGATION_DATABASE_MANAGER
#pragma once

namespace CongregationDatabaseManager
{
    int iEditMenuID;
    int iDeleteMenuID;

    static const COLORREF GetAssignedTextColour()
    {
        return theApp.GetNumberSetting(L"Options", L"AssTextColour", PALETTERGB(0, 0, 255));
    }
}
#endif
```

I am trying to get my head around how I can introduce those two variables:

```
int iEditMenuID;
int iDeleteMenuID;
```

But I don't want it readonly as I need to be able to update the values.

I get link errors when I introduce the variables into the namespace:

```
7>CongregationOptionsDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalEditMenuId" (?iLocalEditMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>CongregationOptionsDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalDeleteMenuId" (?iLocalDeleteMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>CongregationSpeakerDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalEditMenuId" (?iLocalEditMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>CongregationSpeakerDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalDeleteMenuId" (?iLocalDeleteMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>ChristianLifeMinistryStudentMaterialDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalEditMenuId" (?iLocalEditMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>ChristianLifeMinistryStudentMaterialDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalDeleteMenuId" (?iLocalDeleteMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>Meeting Schedule Assistant.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalEditMenuId" (?iLocalEditMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>Meeting Schedule Assistant.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalDeleteMenuId" (?iLocalDeleteMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>Meeting Schedule AssistantDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalEditMenuId" (?iLocalEditMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>Meeting Schedule AssistantDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalDeleteMenuId" (?iLocalDeleteMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>WeekendMeetingDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalEditMenuId" (?iLocalEditMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>WeekendMeetingDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalDeleteMenuId" (?iLocalDeleteMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>PublishersDatabaseDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalEditMenuId" (?iLocalEditMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>PublishersDatabaseDlg.obj : error LNK2005: "int CongregationDatabaseManager::iLocalDeleteMenuId" (?iLocalDeleteMenuId@CongregationDatabaseManager@@3HA) already defined in CongregationDlg.obj
7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Release\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Comment: introduce them where, and why would they be read-only by default?

Comment: what makes you think "being in a namespace" is correlated with "being readonly"?

Comment: It's not clear at all what's preventing you from doing that. There's nothing special about namespaces.

Comment: @molbdnilo using `inline int ...` seems to work.

Comment: @Andrew - If that is a header file, you should consider making the function `inline` as well. Otherwise you get a separate static function in each place the header is included.

Comment: @BoP So inline const etc instead of static const.

Comment: Yes, that would do it.

Answer (score 2):

you are getting multiple definition errors, meaning you are defining the variable or function more than once.

This can easily happen when defining a variable in a header file, and i guess you are trying to get around this by using static.
From the code it isnt clear what you are doing, but if i were to guess, you are doing something like:

```
namespace WhatEver {
 int VariableForCountingThatIWantToReachGlobally = 10;
}
```

the problem is that when doing this, is that

```
int WhatEver::VariableForCounting = 10;
```

will be defined in every file including the header. You get duplicates, so your compiler says "hey! i dont think this is what you want?"

any variable not declared static is by default extern, meaning it can be reached from all translation units (simplified: your other .cpp files)

What you want is a variable to access from everywhere, i am guessing?

there are various ways to accomplish this, what makes this sort of tricky is that you do not want to duplicate the variable.
A simple solution - not necessarily a good solution - (code is bugprone, difficult to maintain and understand, etc.)
So be warned. :)

--in .cpp file 1:--

```
int MyGlobal = 10;
```

--in .cpp file 2:--

```
extern int MyGlobal; 
 // this tells the compiler/linker: "don't worry!, i promise MyGlobal does exist somewhere!

//this could also be in a namespace
 extern int WhateverSpace::MyGlobodoid;
```

--
and thats it, with this solution you never mention the variable name in the headers, and you must realize that "extern" is only for declaring.
The variable must be defined somewhere else.

Lastly, when it comes to stuff like this, its about code organization, and that is a skill. By using classes and instances of them, you can usually get around making globals and get clearer, better code.
Yet sometimes, especially in embedded programming, you just want that one variable from somewhere and don't care.

So consider this a hack more than a proper technique.

BTW. it isnt perfectly clear what you are trying to do, so my answer is very basic. It looks like you are trying to return an instance of something from a free function that is static. Where does that instance come from?

Comment: For the sake of clarity I inserted the variables into the `namespace` as I realise they were missing and hence the confusion. But as mentioned, prefixing my variables (and functions) with `inline` is sufficient.